# Simple Kernel Module

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm writing a simple Kernel module that filter packets. I'm using Ubuntu.

I have in my code

```c
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
```

Yet I still get error when using the Makefile:

```
error: ‘nf_hook_ops’ undeclared
error: ‘NF_IP_FORWARD’ undeclared
error: ‘NF_IP_LOCAL_IN’ undeclared
error: ‘NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT’ undeclared
```

Which seems weird to me because I belive they all should be in

```c
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
```

I'm new to this so if this is not the right forum let me know. If needed more details about my code/ machine let me know.

I cheacked the CONFIG_NETFILTER and they are ok.

Comment: They are under `uapi/linux/...` (which also means they are intended for userspace use and therefore you are probably doing things wrong).

Comment: Got an idea what should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with netfilter. Maybe you can create a question detailing what you are trying to do exactly, as this sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - yes you are failing to include some headers that define constants you need, but why do you need them and what do you want to achieve? What code have you tried writing? Etc.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli `uapi` headers are also used by kernel code, but some parts are conditionally compiled.

Comment: @IanAbbott you're right. That seems to be the case for netfilter where the macros OP wants to use are guarded by `#ifndef __KERNEL__`